# Convergence of integral with absolute function $\int_{0}^\infty |f(x)| dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Given that the following integral *converges*:

$$ \int_{0}^\infty |f(x)| dx$$

Prove or disprove that the following integral also *converges*:
$$ \int_{0}^\infty f(x) dx$$

I thought to use the squeeze theorm in the following way: first we claim that $ \int_{0}^\infty |f(x)| dx$ converges, which implies that $ -\int_{0}^\infty |f(x)| dx$ also converges; using the squeeze theorem I deduce that $\int_{0}^\infty f(x) dx$ also converges. im not sure the squeeze theorem also applies for showing convergence.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both in improper integrals and infinite series: absolute convergence $\;\implies\;$ convergence, because with Cauchy criterion:

$$\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right|\le\int_a^b|f(x)|\,dx\;\left(=\left|\int_a^b|f(x)|\,dx\right|\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume for some region in $[0,\infty]$ $f(x)$ is positive and say it P, P may contain many non-continuous sets and call remaining N for which $f(x)$ is negative.
Now, for N region in $[0,\infty]$ we have
$$|f(x)| = -f(x)= g(x)$$
Than,
$$\int_0^\infty|f(x)|dx = \int_Pf(x) +\int_Ng(x) $$
As, $\int_Pf(x)$ and $\int_Ng(x)$, both are positive and sum of these two positives are giving us a converging value which means that both these integrals converges(have some definite value) in their respective regions in $[0,\infty]$. Also,
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx =  \int_Pf(x) -\int_Ng(x)$$
As it is already proved that these two integrals will converge in their respective regions this proves that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ will also converge. Here P region means it contains all the points on which f(x) is positive.